# Local function/variable encapsulation

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I've seen some code using anonymous immediate-called function for encapsulation look like this

```
(function(){
    var ABC = ...

    function XYZ(){
        ....
    }
})();
```

Are ABC or XYZ() completely inaccessible (through script injection/hijack)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample you provided the variable and function are completely inaccessible out of the self-invoked function scope

Answer (score 2):

An object O is "completely inaccessible" in a scope once the scope has 0 variables referring to either

- the object itself
- any object that O is a descendant property of
- a function that has closed over either of the above

In this case, none of the above are available: you do not have a reference to the contents of `ABC` outside the scope of the IIFE, and you do not have a reference to any objects it is a property of. This means it is now inaccessible. However, if you were to close over `ABC` with `XYZ`, and return `XYZ`, it is now possible to access `ABC` *through* `XYZ`:

```
var outerXYZ = (function(){
    var ABC = "foo";

    function XYZ(){
        return ABC;
    }

    return XYZ;
})();

// no way to access ABC directly, but

var outerABC = outerXYZ();
```

The script injection/hijack part is too vague to answer meaningfully.

Comment: Sorry didn't look what `XYZ` does.